# u64 decimal to hex using C

Tags: c

I have a titleID u64 array in which the first position consists of 16 decimal numbers.

```
u64 titleID[] = {1266656072911941}
```

In this function:

```
APT_PrepareToDoApplicationJump(0, 0x000_LL, 0);
```

How can I replace the `_` with the hex value of `titleID[0]`?
The `0x000_LL` parameter needs to have a u64 type as well.

Example using the provided titleID:

```
APT_PrepareToDoApplicationJump(0, 0x0004800459474C45LL, 0);
```

Comment: you need the pass the number or a string would do?

Comment: It has to be a u64. Strings doesn't work in this case.

Comment: One way to do it, would be just by adding the "0x000" to the start of the first position of the array, and "LL" to the end, after converting the first position itself to hex.

Comment: Whatever you said in the second comment - isn;t it string? appending `"0x00"` etc.

Comment: I'm confused, why wouldn't `APT_PrepareToDoApplicationJump(0, titleID[0], 0);` suffice?

Comment: This is what happens when I try to pass a string. `expected 'u64 {aka long long unsigned int}' but argument is of type 'char *`

Comment: ah... then it is a string...

Comment: @selbie because the required value in the APT funcion needs to have `0x000(The titleID[0] in hex)LL`. I need to change the `titleID[0]` to make it like that first.

Comment: `0x0004800459474C45LL` which is the value I need, is a **long long unsigned int**.

Comment: Please provide an actual [mcve].

Comment: @AnttiHaapala.: The answer provided is not wrong I suppose. Did you check it once? Just asking.

Comment: @coderredoc I didn't downvote it because it is not right. I downvoted it because it is not helpful for the site that you're using your crystal ball and spoonfeeding people and not requesting a [mcve].

Comment: @AnttiHaapala.: Ok..I will delete it and wait for the [mcve] to appear. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: `titleID[0]` is not of type `char *` , so that could not possibly produce the error message that it is of such type

Comment: @M.M.: That's the thing...really. Misguided question and then it's sad that they don't even check when someone answers. I am waiting for 2 hour to undelete my answer because expecting some clarification.(As per the discussion above) Really at time this is too much.

Comment: @M.M I told I get that error *when* I pass a string. I didn't say titleID[0] was a string, which obviously isn't. It was raining here and I was out of internet connection.

Comment: @Antti Haapala My question wasn't clear, and I was clarifying people's doubts here. He had to try something first, of course. Crystal ball? Geez..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hex is a text representation of a number. You don't want hex. You simpy want to pass the number.

```
u64 titleID[] = {1266656072911941}

APT_PrepareToDoApplicationJump(0, titleID[0], 0);
```

is the same as

```
APT_PrepareToDoApplicationJump(0, 1266656072911941LL, 0);
```

and

```
APT_PrepareToDoApplicationJump(0, 0x0004800459474C45LL, 0);
```

They all pass the number one quadrillion, two hundred and sixty-six trillion, ...

Comment: It worked. Thank you.
I used the full number because I didn't want to get downvoted because of people saying "999" should be just a int. Downvoted. Sorry. Thanks.